# .net core console app - publish to different system versions

Tags: powershell, .net-core, console-application, command-prompt, desktop-application

I am working with .net core 2.0 console application. I need to run this console app using command prompt.
Ex: MyApp.exe arguments

This application is gonna be used by internal employees to copy some stuff from shared drive to local drive and update some intranet app.

Employees have different versions of system, like some have windows 10, some have windows 7(x64) and some have windows 7(x86) etc.

With .net core, we can publish a self-contained application as per system version. Like,

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64

dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x64

dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x86
```

and each will have its own published version.

But in this case, I need to ask employees to run the exe as per their system version and it can be tricky with them.

Alternatively, I am thinking to create powershell script which calls different commands according to system version. I will check system version in powershell script and call the exe command for that version.

Is there any way I can do this with .net core only? (without powershell)
Or any other approach I can follow?

Comment: You could perhaps use a tool like [dotGet](https://medium.com/@tonerdo/introducing-dotget-an-installer-for-net-core-cli-apps-9ba79ac7cd89) to handle the process of getting your employees to run an exe-like (as .NET Core produces a dll rather than an exe). Do you really need to produce different stand-alone versions for the different Windows platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x86` (x86 will work on x64 by WOW64)

For more read official [docs about `RID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I tested with win7-x86 and it works for all three win10-x64, win7-x64, win7-x86.   Is there any more benefit of using win-x86 over win7-x86? I had checked the document  but not found any clear information. Could you please suggest?

Comment: @vibs Current is no difference between `win10-x64`, `win7-x64` and `win-x64` if you are not using nuget packages witch using this different RIDs. `x64` vs `x86` is `IntPtr.Size` 8 vs 4